# ShuffleBag (Fisher-Yates + PcgRandom)

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, iterator, shuffle

Anything that could be done better here?

```
public class ShuffleBag<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly int m_endIndex;
    private readonly FastRandom m_rng;
    private readonly T[] m_values;

    private int m_currentIndex;

    public ShuffleBag(T[] values, ulong state, ulong? stream = null) {
        m_currentIndex = 0;
        m_endIndex = (values.Length - 1);
        m_rng = (stream.HasValue ? new FastRandom(state, stream.Value) : new FastRandom(state));
        m_values = values;
    }
    public ShuffleBag(T[] values) : this(values, SecureRandom.GetUInt64()) { }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        var currentIndex = m_currentIndex;
        var endIndex = m_endIndex;
        var rng = m_rng;
        var values = m_values;

        while (currentIndex <= endIndex) {
            var randomIndex = rng.NextInt32(currentIndex, endIndex);
            var temp = values[randomIndex];

            values[randomIndex] = values[currentIndex];
            values[currentIndex] = temp;

            m_currentIndex = currentIndex++;

            yield return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

For those that might inquire, here's the source for [FastRandom](https://github.com/ByteTerrace/ByteTerrace.Maths/blob/master/ByteTerrace.Maths/FastRandom.cs) and [SecureRandom](https://github.com/ByteTerrace/ByteTerrace.Maths/blob/master/ByteTerrace.Maths/SecureRandom.cs).

Comment: Quick observation - I see three different brace styles. Standardize on one. C# de-facto standard is opening and closing braces on their own lines. But that's not important - consistency is. So choose and go forth.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I hesitate to get into the braces thing but will say that I wholeheartedly agree about consistency. The style above is enforced by the IDE automatically; have personally found that defining "classes" of braces in the reformatter helps me parse code easier/quicker (can easily be undone before checking into a repo).

Answer (score 1):

### Enumerate once

I'm not sure whether you intended to write this to be iterable only once. Is this as designed?

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodeReview()
{
    var bag = new ShuffleBag<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });

    var e1 = bag.ToList();  // randomized: "b", "a", "c", "d"
    var e2 = bag.ToList();  // last element: "d"
    var e3 = bag.ToList();  // last element: "d"
}
```

### Collections interfaces

I would let the bag inherit `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` to provide eager access to the bag's size:

```
public int Count => m_values.Length;
```

Comment: I did not intend for that bug but believe it has [already been fixed](https://dev.azure.com/byteterrace/CSharp/_git/ByteTerrace.Maths.Probability.ProbabilisticList?path=%2FProject%2FProbabilisticList.cs&version=GBmaster).

Comment: Ah, you are the one that uses that _New_ static factory method. I remember from a question about native code. I've never seen that naming convention for a factory used before. Does it come from another language?

Comment: It was a technique that I lifted from Java; one can pass constructors around like any other function using `MyClass::new`. AFAIK, C# doesn't support anything like this so I came up with `static T New` as an acceptable alternative. One goes a step further and always makes the actual constructors private in order to force "proper usage" upon consumers (generally just myself).